# Is there an Outlook rule I can apply to a folder to forward all mail dropped into it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, forwarding, rules

We've got a folder in a mailbox on Outlook '07 and I want to set something up so that when an email gets manually dropped into that folder, outlook automatically forwards it to a specific email address and re-files the email to another folder.

So;

Email comes in to inbox - user drags and drops the email to the 'to send' folder - outlook automatically forwards this email to a certain email address - outlook then files this in a seperate folder after it's been sent according to the subject line.

I know you can set up rules so that the email is forwarded as soon as it's received and forward and file emails after this, but this is a request for a rule or something that can apply itself when the email is dropped into the folder rather than received.

The reason we don't want Outlook to automatically forward the email as soon as it's received is that we need to amend or check certain fields before we send it to the correct department.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Damn I need this too, too bad no answers in 8 years

Comment: 11 years now, and I need it also.